# What are the application difference of the circuit breakers which have difference "Circuit Breaker Characteristic Trip Curves"

Tags: power

I know the difference of different type of "Circuit Breaker Characteristic Trip Curves". However, I don't know what are the application difference. Please help

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the question.  Are you looking for why you would want to use different trip curves?

Comment: Searching "motor rated circuit breaker" may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application Differences are Resistive Loads, Transformer Loads and Motor Loads.

The [inrush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current) current for each of these loads is very different. The resistive load could in theory have very little in rush current at turn on. So the circuit breaker does not need much headroom .

The transformer can have an inrush 10 to 50 times the normal current. But it depends on the transformer and the load it's driving.

In fact most coil devices have an inrush current. So the curves allow you to pick the right circuit breaker that allows the load to start (a motor is a good example) with out having to specify some really high value circuit breaker based on the momentary in rush current, but rather choose it based on the normal load. (Needing a 100A or 500A circuit breaker for a 10A transformer is not good from a safety point of view)

Incandescent light bulbs also have an inrush current that tends to not be as bad as a transformer.

---

Edited to change "any coil device has" to "most coil devices have" See comments.

Comment: I'm being a nit-picker with one thing you said - Not all coils have an inrush current - only coils that use a magnetic core that "saturates" due to the power being activated during (or near) a zero cross in the voltage waveform.

Comment: @Andy aka. Yes, your right , I have changed the answer. My only comment would be that the devices I was thinking of that would be protected by a circuit breaker would have a core of sorts. (Motors, transformers, chokes, solenoids etc.)